# After some changes data delete automatically

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I create a project. I want to when I run the form2 form menu bar record will show automatically.

```
access database
vb.net 2010
connecting through coding 
use connecting module
------------------------------------
in form load event 
call connection
call showdata '---*I want to when I run the form2 form menu bar record will show automatically.
----------------------------------------------
call showdata coding

    cnn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    With cnn
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
        .Open()
    End With
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    ds.Tables.Add(dt)
    Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from cominfo", cnn)
    da.Fill(dt)
    cnn.Close()
    If dt.Rows.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("No Company Name Registerd. Please Registered The Company....", vbOKOnly)
        Cominfo.Show()
        Cominfo.ComnameTextBox.Focus()
    Else
        Cominfo.IDTextBox.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(0)
        Cominfo.ComnameTextBox.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item(1)
    End If
```

Coding showing data perfect after add data

But when I other any thing change coding (for example I add a text box for showing the datetime) and save then run the application and goto the form2 all records are delete automatically. then I add record and stop application then run 100 times work properly But when I press the save button after delete/add some blank space of coding window the when I run the application and opened the form2 there are no record.

I Use this code for data inserting on the data

base module

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Module Modconnection
Public cnn, cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
Public cm As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
Public dr As OleDbDataReader

Public Sub connection()
    cn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    With cn
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
        .Open()
    End With
End Sub
```

Add Data button:

```
    Call connection()
    Try

        cm = New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        With cm
            .Connection = cn
            .CommandType = CommandType.Text
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO cominfo (Comname,Add1,Add2,Phone,Vat,cst_tin,Email,Website) VALUES (@Comname,@Add1,@Add2,@Phone,@Vat,@cst_tin,@Email,@Website)"

            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Comname", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.ComnameTextBox.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Add1", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.Add1TextBox.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Add2", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.Add2TextBox.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Phone", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.PhoneTextBox.Text))

            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Vat", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.VatTextBox.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@cst_tin", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.Cst_tinTextBox.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Email", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.EmailTextBox.Text))
            .Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@Website", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar, 255, Me.WebsiteTextBox.Text))


            ' RUN THE COMMAND
            cm.Parameters("@Comname").Value = Me.ComnameTextBox.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Add1").Value = Me.Add1TextBox.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Add2").Value = Me.Add2TextBox.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Phone").Value = Me.PhoneTextBox.Text

            cm.Parameters("@Vat").Value = Me.VatTextBox.Text
            cm.Parameters("@cst_tin").Value = Me.Cst_tinTextBox.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Email").Value = Me.EmailTextBox.Text
            cm.Parameters("@Website").Value = Me.WebsiteTextBox.Text

            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Record saved.", MsgBoxStyle.Information)


            Me.ComnameTextBox.Text = ""
            Me.Add1TextBox.Text = ""
            Me.Add2TextBox.Text = ""
            Me.PhoneTextBox.Text = ""

            Me.VatTextBox.Text = ""
            Me.Cst_tinTextBox.Text = ""
            Me.EmailTextBox.Text = ""
            Me.WebsiteTextBox.Text = ""



            Exit Sub
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    End Try
```

Comment: Please take a moment to understand how the code formatting tools work here. You don't need `<pre>` - just use the icon in the editor, which looks like `{}`. It was unclear what material in this question was code and what was commentary, so I had to guess.

Comment: thank, sir for your reply

Comment: I Just change the db.accdb proprieties copy to out put directory "Do not Copy" 
Thanks to All

Answer (score 1):

I Just change the db.accdb proprieties copy to out put directory "Do not Copy"

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is that you are only editing the Data in your local DataTable, So if you exit and get back to the program it is gone!

So what you need to do is to create an OleDb command and create an "Insert' statement or an "Update" one. I will leave you with a link with more info.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.insertcommand(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5yeecx59(v=vs.110).aspx

Edit: A good video that showcases a working code(not mine):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWP8geR76kI

Comment: I Use this code for data inserting on the data base

Comment: I Use this code for data inserting on the data base code is too many words so, i add the code on the top (main command area. Please check please help me sir....................

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: NO SIR, NO ERROR ARE SHOW, JUST AFTER SAVING WHEN I RUN THE APPLICATION DATA DELETE AUTOMATICALLY

Comment: Honestly I am not too sure then. The code looks fine from what I can see...

Comment: i CAN'T FIND ANY ERROR! BECAUSE I AM BEGINNER IN VB.NET IT IS VERY MYSTERIES FOR ME, HAVE ANY CODE FOR ADDING DATA IN DATABASE (SUBSTITUTE)

Comment: Hmm, I will give you an example code , let me modify my answer

Comment: I Just change the db.accdb proprieties copy to out put directory "Do not Copy" 
Thanks to All